# Object tags (SVG's) preventing jquery from working?

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

Has anyone encountered object tags preventing any jQuery from working? I have a scroll down function on a ul with svg's and a png fallback image, when I delete the object tag and leave the fallback png, the jQuery works...

Here's my code:

```
<ul>
  <li id="toGBR-sticky" onclick="loadingScroll(1000);">
    <object data="assets/icons/gbr2-chapter-nav.svg" type="image/svg+xml" style="width:100%;display:block;margin: 0 auto;">
      <img src="assets/icons/gbr2-chapter-nav.png" style="width:100%;display:block;margin: 0 auto;" />
    </object>
  </li>
  <li id="toCT-sticky" onclick="loadingScroll(1400);">
    <object data="assets/icons/ct-chapter-nav.svg" type="image/svg+xml" style="width:100%;display:block;margin: 0 auto;">
      <img src="assets/icons/ct-chapter-nav.png" style="width:100%;display:block;margin: 0 auto;" />
    </object>
  </li>
  <li id="toHoB-sticky" onclick="loadingScroll(1400);">
    <object data="assets/icons/hii-chapter-nav.svg" type="image/svg+xml" style="width:100%;display:block;margin: 0 auto;">
      <img src="assets/icons/hii-chapter-nav.png" style="width:100%;display:block;margin: 0 auto;" />
    </object>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Show us your Javascript code.  If that is the bit that's not working, it would be the useful bit to see.

Comment: function scrollToAnchor(aid){
    var aTag = $("a[name='"+ aid +"']");
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top-60},{ duration: 2000, queue: false });
}
// LINKS FROM DOWN ARROWS
$("#toGBR").click(function() {
   scrollToAnchor('gbr1');
}); Here it is, its works without the object tag which is weird...

Comment: How about making a fiddle or linking a demo page or something?  The code you have provided isn't much help.  What is the element with id "#toGBR"?  Where are the <a> elements the function references?